# Relation between the number of facets and of free faces

Tags: simplicial-complex

First, give the definition.

1. A **facet** is any simplex in a complex that is not a face of any larger simplex. (aka maximal face)
2. A simplex $\tau$ is called a **free face** if it is the face of only one facet in a simplicial complex.

Here is an example. Suppose we have a simplicial complex {{1,2,3}, {3,4}}. {1,2,3} and {3,4} are all facets and {4}, {1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3} are free faces. 
Here is my question: is there any research about **the maximal number of free faces** given an arbitrary simplicial complex which has **n** 0-simplex, which can be regarded vertices? Is there any relationship between the number of free faces and of the facets for an arbitrary simplicial complex?

Comment: Your definition of free face is not the usual one.  Normally a free face is required to be a _codimension one_ face of a facet (and not contained in any other facets), so $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are not free faces in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your mention! Do you have any idea that given n 0-simplex, how to construct a simplicial complex which has the maximum number of free faces?